# Why does a delegate method need to save content of a custom class managed object context and in the delegate class managed object context?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, delegates, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm sorry for the weird title, I'm a beginner and didn't really know how to ask this so i'll explain myself:

I'm learning Core Data and currently learning from an Apple sample code. The sample code is for listing books using a table view.

In their AddViewController.h their declare an NSManagedObjectContext like this:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@protocol AddViewControllerDelegate;


@interface AddViewController : DetailViewController 

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end


@protocol AddViewControllerDelegate
- (void)addViewController:(AddViewController *)controller didFinishWithSave:(BOOL)save;
@end
```

AddViewController.m

```
#import "AddViewController.h"

@implementation AddViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up the undo manager and set editing state to YES.
    [self setUpUndoManager];
    self.editing = YES;
}


- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate addViewController:self didFinishWithSave:NO];
}


- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{    
    [self.delegate addViewController:self didFinishWithSave:YES];
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [self cleanUpUndoManager];
}


@end
```

Now, in their delegate method that is in RootViewController which is the main table view screen they perform this code:

```
- (void)addViewController:(AddViewController *)controller didFinishWithSave:(BOOL)save {

    if (save) {

        NSError *error;
        NSManagedObjectContext *addingManagedObjectContext = [controller managedObjectContext];

        if (![addingManagedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

        if (![[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

    // Dismiss the modal view to return to the main list
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And I don't get why do they save it to the managedObjectContext of the AddViewController class..?
I thought the hole idea behind setting the root view controller the delegate is so we can preform the saving in there and passing the context object and then save it...

Please help me get it :/

Comment: Where does the AddViewController's NSManagedObjectContext variable is from? It's from AppDelegate, right?

Answer (score 0):

In Appdelegate.m

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContextInternal
{
if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

assert([NSThread isMainThread]); // must be creating context on main thread (though it might get read on a background thread from the library importers, but only to create the child contexts)

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    __managedObjectContext.undoManager = nil;
    [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    [self debugClearArtwork];
}

return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

When you want to save data after creating or update

```
  [APP_DEGATE saveContext]
```

Everywhere in your project just to use 1 NSManagedObjectContext and should call in mainThread. This is the best practice if you don't want to create NSManagedObjectContext in background thread.

Comment: so because i'm not declaring - (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext in my AddViewController.m I have to call it from the main thread..? @nmh

Comment: Do not understand. In AddViewController.m, how can you get NSManagedObjectContext? Is it got from AppDelegate? If YES, I think everything is OK.